# Nginx location block doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I am trying to configure nginx server to handle requests to /awstats differently than all other requests. I have done so for /fpm-status too. However, this particular location doesn't seem to work. I have tried all permutations of location matching. The exact problem is that the location "/awstats" too gets rewritten to the php url. Can someone please point me the mistake in below configuration?

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;

ssl    on;
ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/domain.key;

server_name domain.tld;

root   /var/www/html/project/;
index  index.php index.html index.htm;

location ^~ ^/awstats {
            root /var/www/awstats/domain.tld/;
            index awstats.domain.tld.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/awstats-icon/ {
            alias  /var/www/awstats/icon/;
    }

location ~* \.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

location ~ ^/fpm_status {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow 43.252.193.74;
    allow 172.31.3.18;
    deny all;
}

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 365d;
    }

rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap last;
rewrite ^/googlebase.xml$ /index.php?route=feed/google_base last;
rewrite ^/system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found last;
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_3 1$rule_3;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_3 2$rule_3;
}
if ($uri !~ ".*.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)"){
    set $rule_3 3$rule_3;
}

rewrite ^/api/((?!apidoc).*) /index.php?route=api/$1 last;
rewrite ^/admin_api/((?!adminapidoc).*) /admin/index.php?route=admin_api/$1 last;
rewrite ^/((?!admin|favicon|awstats|fpm_status|robots)(.*)) /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.tld.access.log timed_combined;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your location statement appears to be confusing *prefix* location and *regular expression* location syntax:

```
location ^~ ^/awstats
```

The `^~` modifier is used with a *prefix* location to change its evaluation order, but here you have specified a *regular expression* parameter.

Use either:

```
location ^~ /awstats
```

or:

```
location ~ ^/awstats
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Tried both right now. Sadly either didn't work. I've even tried exact match. That too didn't work.